# How to clone github repo with ajax and display in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, git, github

I'm attempting to pull in a clone of some text I've written and stored on github using ajax.  I want to display that text in html on a webpage.  I've used the curl command through my terminal and was able to get access to it.  I'm trying to recreate that.

```
$.get(url, function(repo){
  $("div").append("<p>"+repo+"</p>")
})
```

These are the errors I'm getting.

This returns an error `Refused to execute script because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(res) {
        alert(res);
        $("div").append("<p>"+res+"</p>");
    }
});
```

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the cross-domain policy, which, in sort, means that using a client-side script you cannot request data from another domain.

You can use any server-side script to prefetch you the content (for example PHP):

```
echo file_get_contents('http://google.com');
```